# Evaluating the return value of an assignment statement

Tags: c

My understanding is that when evaluating an assignment statement in C, the value assigned is also returned.

 However, when I run the code below, this does not seem to be the case. When source_next_level (a GLib queue) is empty, the g_queue_pop_head() function returns NULL, which is then assigned to current_q_node.
The != NULL comparison in the while loop conditional check however does not seem to evaluate this comparison since the while loop is entered even when current_q_node is NULL.

Why is the while loop entered when g_queue_pop_head returns NULL?

```
while((current_q_node = g_queue_pop_head(source_next_level)) != NULL);
{
  if(current_q_node == NULL) puts("It doesn't seem this should ever be printed but it is");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while((current_q_node = g_queue_pop_head(source_next_level)) != NULL);
                                                                    ^^^
```

you have an extra `;` above.

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I didn't see that.